# Firebase data update

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to change the user role.
I have a collection of users with the user id. Each user has fields with mail, name, role, etc.

```
DatabaseReference reference;
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
reference.child(document.getId()).child("Role").setValue("3");
```

document.getId() shows the correct user id but nothing changes in the database

[Database screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuqaY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it was stupid mistake. I'm working on Cloud Firestore and I've tried to change to
Realtime Database

Correct

```
DocumentReference docfer=db.collection("users").document(document.getId());
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Role","3");

 docfer.update(map)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot displays a Firestore database and **not** a Firebase Realtime Database. Both are apart of Firebase services but are actually two totally different products. So you need to use method that are apart of Firestore SDK. To change the value of the "Role" property, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference usersRef = rootRef.collection("users");
DocumentReference uidRef = usersRef.document(uid);
uidRef.update("Role", "3").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.d("TAG", "The document is updated successfully!");
        }
    }
});
```

The result will be the update of the "Role" property from "0" to "3".

Comment: ye i know. I added a solution in response as I understood the mistake but I left it as if someone else made a similar mistake

Comment: I haven't tried because I fix it before you gave your solution

Answer (score 0):

Use "update" :

```
reference.child(document.getId()).child("Role").update("3");
```

than "setValue":

```
 reference.child(document.getId()).child("Role").setValue("3");
```